# How to identify PDF resolution using PDFBox?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am using the pdf box and would like to know how do I identify the resolution of the PDF or the page read?

Comment: PDF files are vector graphics, they don't have an inherent resolution. Do you perhaps want to find out the resolution of a specific bitmap image embedded in the PDF?

Comment: I found an example of how to extract images from the PDF page with the PDFBox, in the example (https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/tags/2.0.3/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/util/PrintImageLocations.java) the value 72 is used for calculation. My question is, where does this 72 dpi fixed value come from?

Comment: // displayed size in inches at 72 dpi rendering
imageXScale /= 72;
imageYScale /= 72;

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve? This sounds a little bit like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) and telling us what your end goal is could help us guide you towards a solution.

Comment: Furthermore, is there a reason why you reference a PDFBox 2.0.3 example, a version nearly four years old? Why not the corresponding current example?

Comment: I have a class that extracts images from pdf. I can extract the images to obtain the width and height, however I need to obtain the exact location (X and Y) of the image on the page. I saw this example mentioned above, and I was in doubt about why the value of 72 dpis is used to define the scale.